# Doing basic validation in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi Im trying my hands on ionic and angularjs. I have a sample code that deals with the phone-list. The working of the code is to add the phone number to the list and delete the selected and also when a number is entered it should check if the number exist there, if the number is not in existence then it should add it. The problem I face here is in checking the existence of the phone number in the list.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/y7D4r/44/)

```
 $scope.phonelist = [];
    $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.phonelist.push($scope.phone);
      $scope.phone = {};
    }
    $scope.removeSelected = function() {
      var i = $scope.phonelist.length;
      // reversed loop because you change the array
      while (i--) {
        var phone = $scope.phonelist[i];
        if (phone.checked) {
          $scope.phonelist.splice(i, 1);
        }
```

Comment: will jquery function help you?

Comment: No. Im using ionic and angularjs @SatishMavani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.phonelist = [];
var added;
$scope.add = function() {
    added = false;
    for (var j=0;j<$scope.phonelist.length;j++) {
        if (angular.equals($scope.phonelist[j], $scope.phone)) {
            added=true;
        }
    }
    if (!added) {
        $scope.phonelist.push($scope.phone);
        $scope.phone = {};
    } else {
        alert('error');
    } 
}
```

Update your controller like this for add function . Thanks

Comment: Can you put it in JSFiddle. Because when I used the logic it didn't work for me. @Ujjwal kaushik